# What is the right way to enable wifi when it was disabled by tlp?

Tags: linux

When I set this in tlp: `DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"`,
what would be the proper way to manually enable wifi when I want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: rtfm
https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/radio.html

> Enable, disable, toggle or check the state of builtin bluetooth, NFC,
> Wi-Fi and WWAN (3G/UMTS, 4G/LTE or 5G) radios:
>
> ```
> bluetooth [ on | off | toggle ] 
> nfc [ on | off | toggle ] 
> wifi [ on | off | toggle ] 
> wwan [ on | off | toggle ]
> ```